# How can I use Azure Data Factory to get 1000 rows at a time from REST API until there are no more rows?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am importing data from a REST API to an Azure SQL Server database. The API times out after 15 seconds so I can only select a limited number of rows at a time. I am using Azure Data Factory.

This is how I query this data using an HTTP client.

```
query{
    orders(limit: 1000, offset: 0) {
    id
    name
    }
}
```

Then the offset is incremented by 1000. For example:

```
query{
    orders(limit: 1000, offset: 1000) {
    id
    name
    }
}
```

The offset value is repeatedly incremented by 1000 until no more rows are returned. How can I use Azure Data Factory to get 1000 rows at a time from the REST API until there are no more rows?

Comment: It might be easier to have another service, like a Logic App or Azure Batch, download the data. Once all the data is downloaded, then the data factory can process the folder. It's also a nice separation of concerns and makes it easier to handle errors and failures.

Comment: That could work as a last resort, but I want to keep the process within ADF.

Comment: Totally agree with Joel - not the best tool for the job, especially if you want to be insulated from failures.
Not sure what have you tried in ADF, but I would probably create a pipeline with a counter variable and  UNTIL activity that would initiate a COPY or WEB activity as long as the counter >= 0. This counter would be incremented if WEB activity returns any data and set to -1 if no data is returned (using IF CONDITION activity), and could be multiplied by 1000 in the dynamic content of WEB activity to increment the offset.

Comment: @JoelCochran I am trying to move data using Azure Function --> ADF's Web Activity, but I am not able to get data more than 3300 rows for one particular table because it is over 4 MB. How would you tackle the issue? This is my post (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/700102/how-to-scale-out-the-size-of-data-moving-using-azu.html?childToView=724057#answer-724057) Thanks!